# d3js with django/python modify csv file

Tags: jquery, python, django, d3.js

I have a list of csv files stored in my server, and I use d3js to display them to users using table rendering with d3.js , and I use django do the server side work. However, I want to add a new function, i.e., when user click a value in the table, they can changed them, and of course, the modifications are also employed on the true file (the one I stored in server). My idea is label every value a row and  col id, and when user modify a value, I use ajax passing the new value and row-col id to server, on server side, there is a function modify csv file with these 3 input.  I would like to know is there any demo or other better way to handle this task.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will generally avoid your approach by using pure file based csv.

Constant disk/IO operations are expensive to server ([Read this FAQ](http://www.mcobject.com/in_memory_database) may help you understand more), and may introduce a race condition  with multiple users trying to update the same table, that csv will then => **read/write** <-> **access/lock** etc.

Personally I'd suggest a combination of using [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database (like [Redis](http://redis.io/), [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) etc.) as a storage backend for your **d3.js**, communicate between **server** <-> **clients** by using [WebSocket](https://www.websocket.org/aboutwebsocket.html) - [Pub/Sub](http://wamp.ws/faq/#pubsub) message (with ajax as a fallback).

**Read/Write** the table state through a [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_management_system) system ([Celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/) or just with your NoSQL).

If you're so insisted, you can also have a periodical storage backup by writing custom server scripts to dump/export the storage (table data) to a csv file.

I hope my explanation and suggestion will guide you to the right direction and eventually finding your best implementation (everyone's use case is different). Good Luck!

Comment: Hi, very good suggestion, if I just provide the task I mentioned before, I will follow your suggestion. But another reason is I must keep them with csv, because my website was reused several software that can only accept csv files. And another thing is, maybe every week, only 10 or 20 tasks like that would be performed. So do you have any idea with using pure csv file?

Comment: @cityCoder, if you're so insisted to use csv, it's still possible. may I ask what backend you're intended to use for the api end points? Instead you can write your own api with just simple json/django view combination and read/write from/to your csv file.

Comment: I download some tools which can give some output based on user input, like perform math computation tasks for user. Given some statistical results. Those tools output csv files, so I want to process csv file directly. Thanks for your information. I will json/django do it~